# Javascript to check whether a checkbox is being checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript routine that is performing actions on a group of checkboxes, but the final action I want to set the clicked checkbox to checked or unchecked based on if the user was checking the box or unchecking.

Unfortunately, every time I check for whether it is being checked or unchecked, it returns "on" indicating the user is always checking the box!  Any help would be appreciated, I've also included the javascript.

```
// Uncheck all the checkboxs with the same Tax Credit
for (i=0; i<arrChecks.length; i++)
{
    var attribute = arrChecks[i].getAttribute("xid")
    if (attribute == elementName)
    {
        // if the current state is checked, unchecked and vice-versa
        if (arrChecks[i].value == "on")   // <-- This is always returning true, even if the box is being unchecked
        {
            arrChecks[i].checked = 1;
        } else {
            arrChecks[i].checked = 0;
        }

    } else {
        arrChecks[i].checked = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct way to check a checkbox in html is checked="checked"

Comment: Have you considered libraries like jquery, prototype, moo or yui? They make this a bit easier

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be evaluating against the checked property of the checkbox element.

```
for (i=0; i<arrChecks.length; i++)
{
    var attribute = arrChecks[i].getAttribute("xid")
    if (attribute == elementName)
    {
        // if the current state is checked, unchecked and vice-versa
        if (arrChecks[i].checked)
        {
            arrChecks[i].checked = false;
        } else {
            arrChecks[i].checked = true;
        }

    } else {
        arrChecks[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was working on some other project and this code works perfectly when you use the code if (arrChecks[i].checked)

Answer (score 20):

The `value` attribute of a `checkbox` is what you set by:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test' value='1'>
```

So when someone checks that box, the server receives a variable named `test` with a `value` of `1` - what you want to check for is not the `value` of it (which will never change, whether it is checked or not) but the `checked` status of the checkbox.

So, if you replace this code:

```
if (arrChecks[i].value == "on") 
{
    arrChecks[i].checked = 1;
} else {
    arrChecks[i].checked = 0;
}
```

With this:

```
arrChecks[i].checked = !arrChecks[i].checked;
```

It should work. You should use `true` and `false` instead of `0` and `1` for this.

Comment: So the code will come out to be: "if (arrChecks[i].checked) arrChecks[i].checked = 1;". That's not right either.

Comment: fair enough. didn't look at the logic there. fixed.

Answer (score 5):

To toggle a checkbox or you can use

```
element.checked = !element.checked;
```

so you could use

```
if (attribute == elementName)
{
    arrChecks[i].checked = !arrChecks[i].checked;
} else {
    arrChecks[i].checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function enter_comment(super_id) {
    if (!(document.getElementById(super_id).checked)) {
        alert('selected checkbox is unchecked now')
    } else {
        alert('selected checkbox is checked now');
    }
}
```

`<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="1" value="1" onclick="enter_comment(this.value)" />`

`<input type="checkbox" name="b" id="2" value="2" onclick="enter_comment(this.value)" />`

Answer (score 3):

```
function CHeck(){
    var ChkBox = document.getElementById("CheckBox1");
    alert(ChkBox.Checked);
}

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="CHeck()" />
```

Comment: (-1) should be ChkBox.checked because it is case sensitive. I spent ~20 minutes trying to get your example to work before I realized the error!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is, but I am pretty sure this will fix it.

```
for (i=0; i<arrChecks.length; i++)
    {
        var attribute = arrChecks[i].getAttribute("xid")
        if (attribute == elementName)
        {
            if (arrChecks[i].checked == 0)  
            {
                arrChecks[i].checked = 1;
            } else {
                arrChecks[i].checked = 0;
            }

        } else {
            arrChecks[i].checked = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you test it both in firefox and IE. There are some nasty bugs with JS manipulated checkboxes.