# How to check if a checkbox is checked or unchecked with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check weather a checkbox is checked or unchecked. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function EnableDisableToolTip() {
    if (document.forms[0].help_text.checked) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
    else if (!document.forms[0].help_text.checked) {
    alert("Unchecked");
    }        
}
</script>


<div id="tooltiponoff">
<form action="">
@Html.CheckBox("help_text", true, new { id = "help_text", onclick = "EnableDisableToolTip()" })Hjælpetekst
</form>
</div>
```

It only alerts Unchecked when i click it

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to check whether a checkbox is being checked or unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473562/javascript-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-being-checked-or-unchecked)

Comment: check what `alert(document.forms[0].help_text)` gives.. ? May be if undefined, it would always go in else condition..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work for me - please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/Rg7zZ/). Note that the event listener is added by Javascript, instead of using the inline `onclick` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
< script type="text/javascript" >
function EnableDisableToolTip(Control) {
    if (Control.checked) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
    else {
    alert("Unchecked");
    }        
}
< /script >


< div id="tooltiponoff" >
< form action="" >
@Html.CheckBox("help_text", true, new { id = "help_text", onclick = "EnableDisableToolTip(this)" })Hjælpetekst
< /form >
< /div >
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are correctly referencing the object by using the console or alerting document.forms[0].help_text.  It's very likely it's not the right reference.

```
alert(document.forms[0].help_text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very well but not greatable. For example when many click the checkbox after 1 unclick then checkbox is start over. My English so bad i cannot explain But: You check many checkbox and then fall the if statement. And then unclick one, this is falling else statement. And checked ones falling down. Your code is developing like this:

```
            var count = 0;
            function Tik(Control) {
                if (Control.checked) {
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    count--;
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    document.getElementById("btnMessageDel").disabled = false;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("btnMessageDel").disabled = true;
                }
            }

<input type="submit" id="btnMessageDel" name="btnMessageDel" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete" form="messagesform" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" value="@MessageId" name="chkMessage" id="chkMessage" onclick="Tik(this)" />
```