# JavaScript code for combining for loop, text, checkboxes, result

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to complete an exercise for a JavaScript class and I'm confused about the order of code. The exercise is this: we are gathering survey information in a form. Instructions: use a for loop to find out which checkboxes are selected (user can select up to 4) and display their value in the result message. The choices for the checkboxes are red, blue, orange and purple.

Any help anyone can offer would be most appreciated. This is my first question on stackOverflow so begging pardon if I have not adhered to all the guidelines. Thank you!

Comment: Gather your checkbox elements to a variable and iterate over your result (in a for loop). You may need to determine how many elements you found to use it in a for-loop. In that loop you can determine what was selected. -- I'm not sure how to help here without writing a complete solution.

Comment: @James McLaughlin, the question is how do I do it? I'm having trouble combining concepts.

Comment: @MizRubyShoes go here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/473562/1146022 and read over it carefully

Comment: and while you're at it, look up getAttribute(): http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a simple way: http://jsfiddle.net/V5a8V/

Comment: The combination of your suggestion and the one from @Justin is working. Thank you so much. I feel like I can figure this out now. Grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the basic steps (in order):

1. Get a list of checkboxes from the DOM (this will result in an array of DOM objects)
2. Loop through the array with a `for` loop to count how many of the checkboxes are checked.
3. Display the count

Exactly how you do step 1 depends upon the HTML you have so you would have to post the HTML before we could advise more specifically (without making wild guesses).

Looping with a `for` loop is nothing more than a basic iteration of an array using a `for` loop.  You should be able to find out how to do that in your course materials where it covers the `for` loop.

Displaying the count can be done any number of ways.  The simplest would be using an `alert()` message.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is exactly what I needed. I was confused about what order to set everything in motion. I'll give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch:

```
var checkboxes = { 
  red: getElementByID('red'),
  blue: getElementByID('blue'),
  orange: getElementByID('orange'),
  purple: getElementByID('purple')
};

var resultMessage = "";
for (var name in checkboxes) {
  resultMessage += name + ": " + checkboxes[name].selected + "\n";
};

alert(resultMessage);
```

getElementByID is a sample method -- you'll need to supply your own.

Comment: Thank you, Justin! I was on the right track but I had included a few lines of code I didn't need (evidence of my rookie status.) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a live demo: [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qvvLQ/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qvvLQ/)

Very simple.

I used jQuery since it is easier to use: **(Here's *a part* of it)**

```
function findIt(){
    var ele=$("input"),                 //get all checkboxes
        obj={};                         //create an object that store information

    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
        var e=ele[i];
        obj[$(e).attr("value")]=e.checked;   //store data in obj
    }
    for(key in obj){
        alert(key+": "+((obj[key])?"Checked":"Not checked"));    //recall it
    }
}​
```

You can also use *`obj`* in another `function`s to do other stuff with it.
Live demo: [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qvvLQ/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qvvLQ/)

Comment: and use getAttribute('value') to get the value of the ones that were checked

Comment: @Derek: Because it's bad code (jquery has `.val()` to access the value and there is `.each()` to iterate over a jquery object.). And `key` is a global variable in your code.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, No code is perfect. And my example is positively working.