# Store value in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am defining a JavaScript array which would be holding a row no and col no of a checkbox which is getting clicked and if checkbox is checked, I will assign the value of row no and col no to 1, else I will put 0.

I need to do some operation based on check and uncheck of checkbox and store the 1,0 in DB.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
var sampleArray=new Array();

function setAll(column, value) {
        
        var i, n = column.length;
        for (i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
            column[i] = value;
        }
      }

if (//some condition){
    if(cell is checked)
        setAll(sampleArray,1); // here i am calling a function and setting the value in index to 1;
    } else if (cell is unchecked)
    {
        setAll(sampleArray,0);
    }
```

The problem with above code is it's not storing the value of all the actions (check and uncheck).

Can somebody help me out in this? is it possible to create a hashmap kind of function inside JavaScript?

```
H<key, value>
```

where key would be col no and row no, and value would be 0 or 1.

Comment: How does Java relate to this?

Comment: You might want to return the modified array or just not send the array since it looks like it is a global variable.

Comment: why `setAll(sampleArray,1);`, then in that function you set them ALL to that value? no where do I see you reference the index of the check in the set of checks.  We need more information to help you better/more/at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setAll(column, value) {

    var i, n = column.length;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        column[i] = value;
    }
return (column)
  }

if (//some condition){
if(cell is checked)
   sampleArray= setAll(sampleArray,1); // here i am calling a function and setting the value in index to 1;
} else if (cell is unchecked)
{
    sampleArray= setAll(sampleArray,0);
}
```

or if you want to use the global variable

```
function setAll(value) {

    var i, n = sampleArray.length;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        sampleArray[i] = value;
    }
  }

if (//some condition){
if(cell is checked)
setAll(1); // here i am calling a function and setting the value in index to 1;
} else if (cell is unchecked)
{
    setAll(0);
}
```

in order to check if a check box is checked look at[Javascript to check whether a checkbox is being checked or unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473562/javascript-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-being-checked-or-unchecked)