# How to reliabily detect when a checkbox has been checked, no matter how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

I'm looking for a way to detect when a checkbox checked value has been changed. `addEventListener()` or jQuery `on()` mostly work, but neither will detect a change made this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="testCheckbox">

<!--- some other script further down the page, not under my control -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("testCheckbox").checked = true;
</script>
```

Is there a way I can detect this change ? Even something that only works in the latest browsers would be great.

Edit: To be clear, I want to detect changes made by any script on the page. I don't necessarily control them, so I can't trigger an event myself.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473562/javascript-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-being-checked-or-unchecked) might help

Comment: @mikel you should fire the `change` event manually after changing the value

Comment: I dont think there's any silver bullet here. Best you can do is subscribe to the `change` event in jQuery and make sure that every time you change the check state you ensure you call `trigger('change')`.

Comment: Since your edit, your code snippet is misleading. You said you can't trigger an event yourself, but this is kind of what your code is doing, it's changing the checkbox value, so instead of doing it that way, use @Matt's answer

Comment: There is also the not elegant solution to check regularly. But only if really no other solution is available.

Comment: @jerome.s Sorry if it's misleading. Unfortunately I can't do that as my actual use case is for writing a plugin that will be used on various sites, so I have no control over what the scripts on the page will do.

Comment: @mikel ok that makes more sense now

Comment: Thanks for the DOMAttrModified suggestion, though looks like it's deprecated and causes unacceptable performance. Hmm, perhaps there just isn't a good way yet :(

Comment: @JanDvorak: DOMAttrModified won't help: the "checked" attribute does not change when the checkbox is checked or unchecked. The "checked" attribute corresponds to the `defaultChecked` property.

Comment: @TimDown the documentation suggests that `DOMAttrModified` actually picks up property changes as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak Only if the property changes an attribute as well, which the `checked` property does not.

Comment: Note: a MutationObserver listening on attribute changes won't pick this up either.

Comment: @TimDown note that if you didn't downvote me so hastily, I would have got the Disciplined badge (which is extremely rare among bronze badges ;-) )

Comment: @mikel you should be able to detect the changes through jQuery by hooking `$.fn.attr`

Comment: @JanDvorak: I decided the downvote was harsh and that I was being an idiot, tried to undo it but you'd hastily deleted your answer :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23306/discussion-between-tim-down-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes I've hooked attr and prop in jQuery, and can pick up changes that way. It's just the straight JS way that's the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth (not much, I'd say), you can do this in IE only using its proprietary `propertychange` event. In other browsers, I'm pretty certain your only option for now is polling.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X4a2N/1/

Code:

```
document.getElementById("testCheckbox").onpropertychange = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.propertyName == "checked") {
        alert("Checkedness changed!");
    }
};
```

Comment: That won't work if you change the checkbox value in javascript like this : `document.getElementById("testCheckbox").checked = true` That's what the OP is after.

Comment: @jerome.s Yes it does. Look at the jsFiddle.

Comment: my bad, I didn't read it properly, I just saw that you said it's working in IE only.

Comment: In other browsers, you should be able to use mutation observers.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, you can't, as I've explained. No attribute changes, and MutationObservers do not observe properties.

Comment: @TimDown , just thinking, is it possible that using Object.defineProperty to override the setter for .checked and make it fire a change event could work ?

Comment: @mikel: Not sure. I'll have a play when I get a moment.

Comment: @mikel: A quick play suggests that as I would have expected, it's possible (at least in Firefox) but only works when the `checked` property is set explicitly and not when the checkbox is checked by user interaction, so it's not really viable. Nice idea though.

Comment: Thanks Tim. It might not work with user interaction, but then user interaction already fires the change event so that can be tracked that way instead. Maybe a combination of both would work then, if I'm not missing something else.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an elegant way. There is an [`Object.observe`](http://weblog.bocoup.com/javascript-object-observe/) proposal for future versions of Javascript.

For now you should trigger the change event as undefined suggested. You could also define a setter function that sets the value and triggers `change` for you.

Comment: Seems like even in the future, Object.observe wouldn't help in this situation ? All the docs I can find about say it's for JS objects, not DOM elements.

Comment: @mikel Possibly, I can't try it. I was hoping something like `Object.observe(document.getElementById("testCheckbox"), fn)` might work.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You must fire the change event manually.

Actions that invoke the change event:

1. Changing the state of the checkbox by a mouse click
2. Changing the state of the checkbox with an access key
3. Changing the state of the checkbox with the SPACE key

Actions that do not invoke the change event:

1. Changing the value of the checked property from script

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out how to automatically intercept that a checkbox has been checked by script code. Edit: *an elegant way to...*

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's still no way to do this without polling or using a shadow DOM framework like React that monitors state. This is because checkbox/radio `.checked = true` property change is a state change, not a DOM mutation. Here's a demo of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6DHXs/1/