# CheckboxInputElement.onChange event not triggered

Tags: javascript, dart

My code is simple but the line `print("checky changed")` is not run. It should be run because after registering the `onChange` listener, which should print a message when the checked status of the checkbox is changed, I change the checked status of the checkbox two times: first directly, then in a `Timer` executed three seconds later, every time with different values.

If I manually check or uncheck the checkbox, the message is printed.

I really need help with this problem: why the message `"checky changed"` is never printed when `checky.checked`'s value is changed programmatically?

I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script async type="application/dart" src="script.dart"></script>
    <script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checky">
  </body>
</html>
```

and this Dart code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  CheckboxInputElement checky = querySelector('#checky');

  checky..checked = true
        ..onChange.listen((_) {
    print("checky changed");
  });

  checky.checked = false;    
  new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    checky.checked = true;    
  });
}
```

Thank you very much for any kind of help!

Answer (score 2):

The forms option onchange doesn't fire programmatically.
You need to execute the on change method after alter the checked property.
Seb

Comment: But I want it to fire programmatically (like it does when I manually check or uncheck the checkbox with the mouse).

Answer (score 2):

You can dispatch `onChange` event manually:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  CheckboxInputElement checky = querySelector('#checky');
  checky
      ..checked = true
      ..onChange.listen((_) {
        print("checky changed");
      });
  new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    checky.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    checky.checked = !checky.checked;
  });
}
```

Comment: This functions well but I must mention that I put the line `checky.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));` after the `checky.checked = !checky.checked;` because I want the `change` event to be dispatched *after* the change, not before the change. I am still waiting for an answer that explains why the event is not dispatched normally, automatically, as expected, also for the programmatic changes of `checky.checked`. I really thank you! Your answer was helpful because it made my code run! (I upvoted it)

Comment: @silviubogan It shouldn't be triggered by programmatic change of its value by the design(same goes for Javascript)

Comment: If this is true, I need to know what event is triggered by programmatic changes of the checkbox's `checked` property because I want to monitor all its changes.

Comment: @silviubogan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500747/how-to-reliabily-detect-when-a-checkbox-has-been-checked-no-matter-how