# Would like to make "check/uncheck" select-all box

Tags: javascript

```
var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (elems[i].type == "checkbox") {
        elems[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

It can be "checked" to select all boxes but will not uncheck upon "un-check".

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Replacing tab with document, I don't get any errors.

Comment: Not sure but maybe this thread will help you solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473562/javascript-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-being-checked-or-unchecked?rq=1 Hope it helps.

Comment: no error -.-  , the thing i want is to add an unselect function only

Comment: What's preventing you from changing the true to false?

Comment: how do i change the this function upon   which click the unselect checkbox and make it be "false"   ,  i still cant make it right =.="

Answer (score 1):

You can make a master checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
```

Give a generic class to all your other checkboxes, say `cb`

```
document.getElementById("checkAll").onchange = function() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].checked = this.checked;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Sunk/1/

Comment: I think I'm missing something here if you also used `this`.. could you explain?

Comment: this should be inside a click handler for the check all checkbox

Comment: I personally feel that's assuming of the OP.

Comment: @Daedalus -- Updated answer, gives a nice scenario

Comment: I would say +1, but that's apparently discouraged now.

Comment: how could i use this on my code?  the fucntion still doesn;t work when i refer to Mr.tymeJV example

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
elems[i].checked = this.checked;
```

instead of

```
elems[i].checked = true;
```

Comment: please if i want add unselect function too ?

Comment: Well, its wrong depending on what the op actually did.  However, I feel that it would be better to state that this should be in an event handler to execute properly.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the code was part of an event handler. Maybe I am too accustomed to jQuery.

Comment: haha  it's ok  ,  thx jaeheung and Daedalus ... but i stay on coding for almost 2 hrs and still the same ~~~