# Need a javascript the cheks the checkbox if it 'checked'

Tags: javascript, html

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var c = document.getElementById("check").checked;



function che(){
    if (c){
         document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<p><strike>{{tarea.objetivo}}    </strike></p>';
}
}


</script>
```

All I need is that when I check the checkbox apply a  tag to the text. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: A simple google search wil find you plenty of answers...literally the first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473562/javascript-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-being-checked-or-unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for a change event on the checkbox:

```
document.getElementById('check').onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('#check').change(function(){
    if (this.checked){
        // do stuff 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error on the console:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

You need to declare

```
var c = document.getElementById("check").checked;
```

inside the `che()` function.

Change to this:

```
function che() {
    var c = document.getElementById("check").checked;
    if (c) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<p><strike>{{tarea.objetivo}}</strike></p>';
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vrtrsgvn/1/)**